# What is the type for "Rails App Server" in cloud formation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I'm creating an AWS OpsWorks stack using cloud formation.

The documentation says to set the "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer" property "Type" value for the layer type.

From [AWS::OpsWorks::Layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-layer.html) :

> Type
>   The layer type. A stack cannot have more than one layer of the same type, except for the custom type. You can have any number of custom types. For more information, see CreateLayer in the AWS OpsWorks API Reference.
>
> Important
>   If you update a property that requires the layer to be replaced, you must specify a new type unless you have a custom type. You can have any number of custom types.
>
> Required: Yes
>
> Type: String

However, that doesn't list any of the names.

In tutorials I see:

```
MySQL: "db-master"
PHP App Server: "php-app"
```

Is there a complete list?

And a list of the attributes used to configure them?

Comment: Ok, so I found most of the answer it is "rails-app" and documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/APIReference/API_Layer.html. The other attributes are there - but nothing tells me what RailsStack attribute should be for using apache2 & passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, and I suggest it is a good solution for any type of OpsWorks stack:

Create the type of stack you want in OpsWorks first. Set it up, deploy your app exactly as you need it then use the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) tool to describe the Stack, Layers, Instances and App in JSON format.

Eg:

```
$ aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-stacks
$ aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-layers --stack-id <stack-id>
$ aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-instances --stack-id <stack-id>
$ aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-apps --stack-id <stack-id>
```

The values will be in the JSON and you can use that as the basis of your own Cloudformation OpsWorks templates.

Specifically for my question about Rails, here is what my rails app layer looks like:

```
"RailsLayer": {
  "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
  "DependsOn": "App",
  "Properties": {
    "StackId": {"Ref": "Stack"},
    "Type": "rails-app",
    "Name": "Rails App Server", 
    "Shortname": "rails-app", 
    "Packages": [
        "imagemagick"
    ], 
    "EnableAutoHealing": true, 
    "AutoAssignElasticIps": false, 
    "AutoAssignPublicIps": true,
    "Attributes": {
        "RailsStack": "apache_passenger", 
        "RubyVersion": "2.1", 
        "BundlerVersion": "1.5.3", 
        "PassengerVersion": "4.0.46", 
        "ManageBundler": "true", 
        "RubygemsVersion": "2.3.0"
    }, 
  }
```